# Como usar Scanner para definir as caracteristicas do objeto "produto"

Tags: java, array, arraylist, scanner

```
   public static void cadastrarProduto(String nome, int codigo, int quantidade, double valor) {
    var produto = new Produto();
    Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
    nome = leitor.next();
    produto.nome = nome;
    nome = leitor.next();
    produto.codigo = codigo;
    codigo = leitor.nextInt();
    produto.quantidade = quantidade;
    quantidade = leitor.nextInt();
    produto.valor = valor;
    valor = leitor.nextDouble();
    produtos.add(produto);
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi do código possui apenas um erro de lógica. O que confundiu um pouco foi o fato de ter declarado parâmetros no método `cadastrarProduto()`.

Outra coisa é que tentou fazer uma atribuição direta aos atributos da classe `Produto` (isso só funciona se os atributos estiverem declarados como `public` na classe `Produto`), quando na verdade deveria utilizar os setters (ou construtor). Isto é conhecido como encapsulamento.

Apenas refatorei o seu código para tentar fazer o que está descrito no título, usei o scanner para definir as características do objeto produto.

Segue o código refatorado:

```
public static void cadastrarProduto() {
    var produto = new Produto();
    Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String nome = leitor.next();
    produto.setNome(nome);

    int codigo = leitor.nextInt();
    produto.setCodigo(codigo);

    int quantidade = leitor.nextInt();
    produto.setQuantidade(quantidade);

    double valor = leitor.nextDouble();
    produto.setValor(valor);

    produtos.add(produto);
}
```